# Looping code failure

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

I want to make the following code run throughout all my sheets. I have about 20 sheets. What am i missing?

```
Sub Filter1()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count        
       ActiveSheet.Range("$Q$1:$Q$90").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
       ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
       ActiveSheet.Select        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You never actually *use* `i` to select a worksheet?

Comment: change `ActiveSheet` to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)` and remove `ActiveSheet.Select `

Comment: So i did this:' Filter Macro
    
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("$Q$1:$Q$90").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1

    Next i
    
End Sub

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Outline.` also change to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Outline.`

Comment: Sub Filter1()
'
' Filter Macro
    
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("$Q$1:$Q$90").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1

    Next i
    
End Sub

Comment: how exactly it's `still no luck`? clarify please

Comment: sorry for the clutter. it has now worked.using the answer below. I appreciate your help greatly!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Sub Filter1()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("$Q$1:$Q$90").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
    Next i
End Sub
```